WindowMargins and FullScreenArea
I have the following functions, that ideally will draw each monitor as a rectangle, also will draw the notebook. My question is, how does the notebook margins relates to the list returned by FullScreenArea? Looks like in my current implementation, the up and down values of the monitors are somehow reversed:
ClearAll[drawMonitors];
drawMonitors[] :=
    drawMonitors[
        "FullScreenArea" /. SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]
    ]

drawMonitors[displays : {{{_, _}, {_, _}}...}] :=
    Module[{names, rectangles, colors},
        rectangles =
            MapApply[
                Rectangle
                ,
                Map[
                    Function[display,
                        display
                    ]
                    ,
                    Transpose /@ displays
                ]
            ];
        names =
            MapIndexed[
                Text[
                    "Monitor " <> ToString[First[#2]],
                    RegionCentroid[#1]
                ]&,
                rectangles
            ];
        colors = RandomColor[Length[rectangles]];
        Graphics[
            Flatten @
            {
                Transpose[{colors, rectangles}],
                Black,
                names
            },
            Axes -> True
        ]
    ]

ClearAll[drawMonitorsAndNotebook];
drawMonitorsAndNotebook[notebook_] :=
    With[{monitors = drawMonitors[]},
        Dynamic@
        Refresh[
            Module[{origin, left, right, bottom, top, xsize, ysize, nbrectangle},
                origin =
                    First@
                    Transpose@
                    First@
                    Lookup[SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"], "ScreenArea"];
                {{left, right}, {bottom, top}} = AbsoluteCurrentValue[notebook, WindowMargins];
                {xsize, ysize} = AbsoluteCurrentValue[notebook, WindowSize];
                
                nbrectangle =
                    {
                        {
                            left,
                            bottom
                        },
                        {
                            left + xsize,
                            bottom + ysize
                        }
                    };
                
                Show[
                    monitors,
                    Graphics[
                        Rectangle @@ nbrectangle
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]



A couple of comments:  1.) The desktop coordinate space is not the same as Graphics.  In Graphics, the origin is in the lower left corner and goes up and to the right.  The desktop space's origin is the upper left corner and goes down and the right. 2.) The WindowMargins are offsets from each edge of the primary display, not absolute coordinates.  Positive values are inward, negative outward.  So to position things appropriately,  you need to know the dimensions of the primary display.
